# declare a variable as *not* an integer in sage/maxima solve

Tags: python, sage, maxima

I am trying to solve symbolically a simple equation for x:

```
solve(x^K + d == R, x)
```

I am declaring these variables and assumptions:

```
var('K, d, R')
assume(K>0)
assume(K, 'real')
assume(R>0)
assume(R<1)
assume(d<R)

assumptions()
︡> [K > 0, K is real, R > 0, R < 1, d < R]
```

Yet when I run the solve, I obtain the following error:

> Error in lines 1-1
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File
>   "/projects/sage/sage-7.3/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/smc_sagews/sage_server.py",
>   line 957, in execute
>       exec compile(block+'\n', '', 'single') in namespace, locals
>
> ...
>
> File "/projects/sage/sage-7.3/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sage/interfaces/interface.py",
>   line 671, in **init**
>       raise TypeError(x)
>
> TypeError: Computation failed since Maxima requested additional constraints; using the 'assume' command before evaluation *may* help (example of legal syntax is 'assume(K>0)', see `assume?` for more details)
>
> **Is K an integer?**

Apparently, maxima is asking whether K is an integer? But I explicitly declared it 'real'! 
How can I spell out to maxima that it should not assume that K is an integer?

I am simply expecting `(R-d)^(1/K)` or `exp(log(R-d)/K)` as answer.

Comment: See also https://ask.sagemath.org/question/34876/declare-a-variable-as-not-an-integer-for-solve/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The assumption framework in both Sage and Maxima is fairly weak, though in this case it doesn't matter, since integers are real numbers, right?

However, you might want to try `assume(K,'noninteger')` because apparently [Maxima does support this](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/docs/manual/maxima_11.html#Item_003a-integer) particular assumption (I had not seen it before).  I can't try this right now, unfortunately, good luck!

Comment: Perfect, it worked as expected! Thanks, somehow it did not come up in my googling!

Comment: Awesome.  The `noninteger` parameter is not in the Sage doc, as far as I know, only the Maxima one; I've opened https://trac.sagemath.org/ticket/21554 to add it to the doc.  (PS if this indeed answers please accept so that future visitors know this worked without reading the comments.)

Comment: Done - before accepting I wanted to check that my actual code was working fine as well (I posted a toy example only) and it does, thanks again.